# webkit issue on re-coloring "j" character

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

This is really weird and kind of infuriating. I was trying to make a link change color, simple enough, right? No. For some reason, Chrome refuses to change 2 pixels of color on the "j" character when I hover over it. I tried it in Safari and it has the same issue; firefox on the other hand, renders it perfectly.

I have tried changing fonts but the problem persists. Only Arial out of all the fonts I tested didn't have the issue.

<s>Don't know if it matters but the text is wrapped in ol>li>a</s>

When I tried to take a screenshot with :hover forced in chrome developer tools it works perfectly, so I had to take the picture from my phone and use my mouse to hover.

[image]

EDIT: Added [CodePen Demo](http://cdpn.io/BfCbH)
EDIT2: Doesn't seem like being wrapped in ol>li have anything to do with it

Comment: Can you add a fiddle to recreate it?

Comment: @feitla I've added a demo to the main post, it still has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by [subpixel rendering](https://www.grc.com/ctwhat.htm). If you add `opacity: 0.9999;` to the `li a`, it will fix it for you.

UPDATE

You can also do `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` which does not cut off the pixels like the previous solution.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix the issue, but it also chops off a part of the font that is intended in the typeface. Is there somewhere I could read more about this?

Comment: I figured out another solution which I think might be better. Also included a link about subpixel rendering

Comment: Unfortunately the text-rendering solution doesn't seem to work on my computer(OS X 10.8-Chrome). I just opted to changing the hover color to a smokeish color and the original color darker so the stub is less noticeable.